# How to adapt Jstree to use the Adjacency Model?

Tags: php, mysql, class, jstree, adjacency-list-model

Jstree uses the nested set approach and while with static content this worked, we discussed our requirement with Ivan Bozhanov about re-using our table to allow each user to do operations with it and he suggested that we should use the Adjacency model instead.

I've found this library at PHPClasses as it was my last resort, there is not much about it from the documentation at jstree.com/demo but.. what would be the steps that I need to do if I want to use with jstree effectively?

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6135-PHP-Create-and-manipulate-adjacency-lists-in-MySQL.html

Thank you in advance for any guidance you can provide!
JP-

Comment: I also found this script that appears to have switch for using the adjacency model or the nested set or both apparently depending on the values of the DB's table but tried to adapt it and it didn't work either. http://www.bvbcode.com/code/nzkqrcoj-897420 Does anyone know why the jstree v1 pre-stable from Github and jstree.com/demo is not having this by default or is there any way to adapt it. Tried many approaches but is just showing a generic error in the console. Please help!

Comment: obviously it's possible but will take ages and having made it work with the nested set approach by updating in many places the original script I believe that the adjacency model can be discarded for this case.. at least for us.. we are re-using the top parent nodes and updating them on demand at the server included file by passing the session id over and then running a sql to get the min, max values for the left and right where the user id is the logged.. and since using the types plugin to limit the depth to 4 or 5 levels I don;t see a problem with using it as described in posts online